# Shift (update) unique column values in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, unique-constraint

Using MS SQL Server, the following works fine:

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable(mykey int primary key)

INSERT INTO #temptable VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO #temptable VALUES (2)

UPDATE #temptable SET mykey=mykey+1
```

However, using PostgreSQL, the following fails:

```
CREATE TABLE pg_temp.tbl_test(testkey integer primary key)

INSERT INTO pg_temp.tbl_test VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO pg_temp.tbl_test VALUES (2)

UPDATE pg_temp.tbl_test SET testkey=testkey+1
```

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tbl_test_pkey"
>   DETAIL:  Key (testkey)=(2) already exists.

I need to increment every value of one column in one table, which is part of a composite unique constraint. How can I do this in one statement ?

Thanks !

---

Edit: If you are wondering why this makes sense (at least to me), here is a more complete scenario.

I have one table of items organized in categories. Each item has a particular position in the category.

```
category_id (PK) | category_position (PK) | item_attribute_1 | item_attribute_2
1 | 1 | foo | bar
1 | 2 | foo2 | bar2
2 | 1 | foo4 | bar4
2 | 2 | foo3 | bar3
```

This table contains data like:

```
category1 : (foo, bar), (foo2, bar2)
category2 : (foo4, bar4), (foo3, bar3)
```

Note that (foo4, bar4) comes before (foo3, bar3) in category2.
Now if I want to reorder items in one category, I need to update category_position... But because of the PK, I cannot shift values using PostgreSQL as I could with SQL Server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is indeed a bit confusing as all other constraints are evaluated on a statement level, only PK/unique constraint are evaluated on a per row level during DML operations.

But you can work around that by declaring the primary key constraint as deferrable:

```
create table tbl_test 
(
  testkey   INTEGER,
  constraint pk_tbl_test primary key (testkey) deferrable initially immediate
);

insert into tbl_test values (1), (2);

set constraints all deferred;

update tbl_test
   set testkey = testkey +1;
```

Deferred constraints do have some overhead, so by defining it as `initially immediate` this overhead is kept to a minimum. You can the defer the constraint evaluation when you need it by using `set constraint`.

---

The real question however is: why would you need to do this on a primary key value? The PK values has no meaning whatsoever, so it seems rather unnecessary to increment all values (regardless of the DBMS being used)

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I added a more complete scenario in my question. I will have a look at your solution.

Comment: @personne3000: The deferrable attribute works on _constraint_ level so it doesn't matter how many columns the PK has. But having the position as part of the PK seems like a rather strange design. A PK value is meant to be stable, not change frequently. Having to change a PK value each time you insert new items is usually an indication of a bad DB design.

Comment: However I would still like to keep a UNIQUE constraint on those columns, because I do not want 2 items to have the same position in the same category. I do have another candidate tuple for the pkey (which has another UNIQUE constraint); would it be better to use it instead ?

Comment: @personne3000: if you have a "stable" pair of columns for the PK then I would prefer that. You can still define a deferrable unique constraints (not index!) on category_id/position. But if you are going to frequently renumber the position anyway why would you need the unique constraint in the first place? When you renumber it you could assign unique positions to each item.

Comment: I used the other tuple for the PK in the end, and a deferrable unique constraint for the category and order as you suggested. Order will not be updated often: only when an administrator decides to change the display order of some items. I prefer to keep a unique constraint to be sure that my data is valid at database-level. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Solution without altering constraint as `deferrable initially immediate`

```
UPDATE tbl_test t1 
SET    testkey = t2.testkey + 1 
FROM   (SELECT testkey 
    FROM   tbl_test 
    ORDER  BY testkey DESC) t2 
WHERE  t1.testkey = t2.testkey
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/edit/GMJ48099

Comment: If the table is large enough it generates "ERROR: too many range table entries". Any idea how to overcome it?